# add 1 day to date when using CASE WHEN REDSHIFT

Tags: amazon-redshift

I am trying to use a CASE WHEN statement like below to add 1 day to a timestamp based on the time part of the timestamp:

```
CASE WHEN to_char(pickup_date, 'HH24:MI') between 0 and 7 then y.pickup_date else dateadd(day,1,y.pickup_date) end as ead_target
```

pickup_Date is a timestamp with default format YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

```
My output
pickup_Date                         ead_target
2020-07-01 10:00:00                 2020-07-01 10:00:00
2020-07-02 3:00:00                  2020-07-02 3:00:00
```

When the hour of the day is between 0 and 7 then ead_target = pickup_Date ELSE add 1 day

```
Expected output
pickup_Date                         ead_target
2020-07-01 10:00:00                 2020-07-02 10:00:00
2020-07-02 3:00:00                  2020-07-02 3:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the date_part() function to extract the hour of the day - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATE_PART_function.html

Your case statement should work if you extract 'hour' from the timestamp and compare it to the range 0 - 7.